# how to play itunes music's from terminal or aiml pattern

Tags: python, terminal, speech-recognition, launch, aiml

An attempt to make a very simple, Personal Assistant . and my project is based on aiml and uses pyaiml for using the AIML interpreter in python. I want to give a command for my aiml pattern to open iTunes and automatically play a random song, is there to make it work ? Like for example iPhone’s Siri , she starts playing music automatically after she receives a command “play a music”, no need to press the play button

I used this to launch iTunes

````
open -a /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/itunes</system> ```

I tried this ```<system> open -a itunes 1.mp3</system>```
 it automatically starts the music from my python folder
 not from the actual itunes library
````

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/apple/itunes-applescript-examples-scripts-mac-reference

Comment: I already tried but I could not implement that in my aiml code ,